# Could Not Load File or Assembly Sharepoint 2007 WebPart

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint, web-parts

I am playing around with Sharepoint 2007. I have a virtual machine (win server 2k3) with an instance of sharepoint server 2007 running on it. I am now working on creating web parts. I have successfully created simple ones, such as this one that displays text:

```
public class SimpleWebPart : WebPart
{
    private string _displayText = "Hello World!";
    [WebBrowsable(true), Personalizable(true)]
    public string DisplayText
    {
        get { return _displayText; }
        set { _displayText = value; }
    }
    protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.Write(_displayText);
    }
}
```

I have this one (and a few test ones) inside of a Class Library, which I put into the `_app_bin` folder inside of `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80`.

The latest one I added utilizes LINQ to get data from a table I added (not part of Sharepoint):

```
public class SimpleDBWebPart : WebPart
{
    protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        var oDB = new SPWebPartDataClassesDataContext();
        var oRes = oDB.GetAllFirstTable();

        foreach(var item in oRes)
        {
            writer.Write("<div>Item Name: {0}</div>",item.text);
            writer.Write("<div>Item ID: {0}</div>", item.id);
        }
    }
}
```

The `GetAllFirstTable()` is a stored procedure that gets all the data from my test table:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.GetAllFirstTable
AS
    SELECT * FROM FirstTable
    RETURN
```

When I try to add the WebPart to a page, I get this error:

> The "SimpleDBWebPart" Web Part appears to be causing a problem. Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I used Reflector to make sure I have the assembly inside the DLL:
[image]

And that appears to be the case. Do I have to add the assembly to the web.config file of the sharepoint site? Or is there something else that I am missing?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use LINQ or .NET 3.5 feature you need to first configure the SharePoint to run in 3.5 Mode.
Refer to these links on how to do that

[Simplest way](http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2008/10/10/enabling-net-3-5-in-sharepoint-2007-sites-the-lazy-way.aspx)

[AnotherOne](http://skurocks.wordpress.com/2009/01/02/sharepoint-aspnet-35-quick-tips/)

Comment: this has not worked for me yet, I get a server error in '/' Application. I am going to try to work this out. Thanks for the base to narrow my searching down :D

Comment: Enabled the CallStack="True" and CUstomError="Off" in Web.Config, you will get to know the actual error .

Comment: the real problem was I forgot to install .net 3.5 on my server >.<. haha. thanks for the input though :)